# How to hide array element of particular index?

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I want to hide a link if the records are less than 6. The code that I'm using -

```
var link = document.getElementById('id-name');
  if (index<=4){
   link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } 
  else{
    link.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
```

Its working fine if I have 1 record present. But, if I have 0 records its showing the link.

How to hide link if the record is 0.

UPDATE -

Sharing full code for more clarity.

```
function getfunction(token) {
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpRequest.open("GET", "/path");
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                    if (httpRequest.status === 401) {
                        SignOut();
                    } 
                    else {
                        var  data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.response);
                        var d = $(data).get().reverse();
                        $.each(d, function(index, itemData) {
                            var link = document.getElementById('id-name');
                            if (index<=4){
                                link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                            } else{
                                link.style.visibility = 'visible';
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: explain more...

Comment: Show us how you set the value of `index`. Show us your markup. What you are showing _should_ work because `0 <= 4` so there is something _else_ wrong that you have not put in your question.

Comment: @StephenP Added the full code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are doing `$.each(d, function(index, itemData) {` — jQuery's `$.each(...)` iterates over every item that is in `d` and calls the function you provide.

When that function is called it is passed two parameters: the ***current*** index into `d` and the data at that index — `index` does *not* represent the number of items in `d`

> if I have 0 records its showing the link.

If there are zero records then `$.each(...)` ***will not run at all*** so `link.style.visibility = 'hidden';` will never be executed — and I suspect that `'id-name'` is initially visible so it remains visible.

As I understand it, you want `id-name` to be hidden if there are "less than 6" records in `d` — in that case you don't need to loop with `$.each` at all, you can just test the length of `d`

```
if (d.length < 6) {
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
/*    // Don't even need to have the 'else' if the link is initially visible
else {
    link.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here if records are in array :
**you can use this logic in your program :**

```js
let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
let len = arr.length;
if (len < 6) {
  console.log("not show");
} else {
  console.log("show");
}
```